# Creating specific audio HTML5 player page in WordPress

Tags: html

I have a`WordPress` blog with embedded HTML5 audio. I would like to limit it to the main blog post pages instead of other pages. How do I achieve this? My current code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <audio autoplay>
      <source src="https://blog.systechforum.net/blogaudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      <source src="https://blog.systechforum.net/blogaudio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element. Use Firefox or Chrome. 
    </audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll want to add this `audio` tag to one of your WordPress homepage  template file (a php file).

Comment: I already have the HTML5 audio in the blog, I just want to limit it to the main blog posts and not other pages. Right now I use a widget to add the HTML5 code to the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some php code that should accomplish this:

```
<? php
  $homepage = "/"; // modify this to match your home page URL
  $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if($homepage==$currentpage) { ?>
    <audio autoplay>
    <source src="https://blog.systechforum.net/blogaudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="https://blog.systechforum.net/blogaudio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element. Use Firefox or Chrome. 
  </audio>";

<? php } ?>
```

Here's what it's doing:

**1.** Setting a variable equal to the homepage URL.

**2.** Setting a variable equal to the current page URL.

**3.** Comparing the two variables (URLs)

**4.** Showing the audio player if the URLs match.

Comment: I tried that code and although the audio plays, it still plays on all posts like: https://blog.systechforum.net/using-bcrypt-in-your-wordpress-blog/

This is what I have:


<? php
  $homepage = "https://blog.systechforum.net"; 
  $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if($homepage==$currentpage) { ?>
    <audio autoplay>
    <source src="https://blog.systechforum.net/blogaudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="https://blog.systechforum.net/blogaudio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element. Use Firefox or Chrome. 
  </audio>";

<? php } ?>